# Sending high priority message via GCM on Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm using the AzureNotification Hub to send GCM noifications to my Android aplication. My question is by default what priority does the SDK use to send notifications and can this be configured. Based on what I have seen on Google's website https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en I can simply add the priority as part of the payload. However I am not sure how the underlying SDK handles this and if it adds a priority by default. This is what I did. The notification is being sent with the code below but I'm wondering if the priority value has any effect.

```
var payload = new
{
priority="high",
data = new
{
message = new
{
model.Title,
model.Time,
model.Message,
model.NotificationId,
model.NotificationType,
model.SenderFacebookId,
model.TargetId,
model.TargetUserFacebookId
}
}
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(json, Tag.UserDevice.Id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are adding priority (as a sibling of data) should work. The default GCM priority is normal, so if you don't assign a priority it is treated as normal. This means slightly different things on different platforms but in general high priority messages will be delivered ASAP while normal priority messages will be delivered at the next optimal time depending on various device conditions.

On Android GCM priority helps devices decide when to deliver messages when in [Doze](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) mode. Messages that need user action like a chat message should get high priority, Android will try to deliver them ASAP. Most messages like sync new server data should be assigned normal priority, Android will try to deliver them at the next most optimal time for the device.

Answer (score 0):

The priority is indeed followed by the Azure platform https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/  The priority values are actually part of the http header being sent by azure to the Google servers, essentially the notification is still coming via the google server and Azure just sends the bundle to Google , the valid values can be checked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh221551.aspx

Comment: The link you provided is for Windows Phone. That doesn't apply to Android.

Comment: Both links have priorities that are linked to sending Notifications to Windows Phone . I'm asking how this can be done specifically with Android via the Notification Hub. If just adding the value to the payload will suffice